# install .p12 or .cer in console macos

Tags: macos, shell, ssl, certificate, pkcs#12

I've try install .p12 cert to my macos use command line.

I can install .cer

```
sudo certtool I Certificates.p12 d
```

but it doesn't work on computers where this cert is not generated. As I see i should use .p12
But how can I install .p12 ?

I've tried to use

```
security add-certificates "/Users/$NAME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain" "$CERT_PATH"
```

But result same as previous command. Can't install .p12

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It looks like you can do this using the import command. I've managed to do the following:

```
security create-keychain -p password bobbins.keychain
security add-certificates ./MyCertificate.cer

security unlock-keychain -p password bobbins.keychain
security import ./MyPrivateKey.p12 -k bobbins.keychain -P privateKeyPassword
```

I found I had to unlock the keychain, otherwise it prompted for the keychain password.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may also find it helpful to specify the '-a' option for importing your private key. This allows you to specify the path to an application that's allowed to use it without entering the password.

Comment: According to the documentation the allow flag is'-A'. The lowercase is for another purpose.

Comment: The two options (at least as of macOS 10.12): `-A  Allow any application to access the imported key without warning (insecure, not recommended!)` `-T  Specify an application which may access the imported key (multiple -T options are allowed)`

Answer (score 34):

This will import the bundle to the default keychain:

```
security import ./bundle.p12 -P secretPassword
```

`secretPassword` is the p12 file encryption password.

While the answer by Stuart should work, it is not required to create another keychain first.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple. I've managed to do the following:

```
security import ./dev_account.p12 -P password -A
```

It will not prompt for the keychain password. It's works for me.