# Retrieve file from keyvault instead of secure files in InstallAppleCertificate task on azure pipeline

Tags: ios, azure, certificate, azure-pipelines, signing

According to the documentation of the InstallAppleCertificate task, there is a certSecureFile parameter that looks for the certificate in the "Secure Files":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate?view=azure-devops

However in my organization I don't have the permission to upload secure files:
[image: no permissions to upload secure file]

Any other way to select a certificate that isn't uploaded to "Secure Files" for this task?

They did gave me a separate keyvault which I can perfectly link to the pipeline build and get files/secrets from in bash scripts. Yet this InstallAppleCertificate task doesn't allow me to use those instead. I wouldn't even mind to put the certificate in my source repo (I know I shouldn't do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `certSecureFile field` in  InstallAppleCertificate task needs to use the .p12 file in **secure file**.

I am afraid that files that are not in the secure file ***cannot*** be used.

Based on my test, when I use the file from local machine, it will show the following error:

[image]

This means that before running the build, it will retrieve the files in the secure file. And the file needs to exist in secure file.

Since you could get the files/secrets , you could try to install the Apple Certificate(.p12 file) via script.

`security import ./xxx.p12 -P secretPassword`

Here is a thread about [install .p12 or .cer in console macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485806/install-p12-or-cer-in-console-macos).

Comment: Thanks for verifying. I get that same error indeed. Too bad I will try the alternative.